# jQuery not working on IE 9 when retrieve grand child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, dom

The following jQuery doesn't work on IE9. Unfortunately I am on jQuery 1.4

```
var denomAmount = j(this).closest('.denom').children('.denomValue').eq(0).val();
```

Dom structure is like this

```
<tbody class="denomTable">
    .......
    <tr class="denom">
        ...........
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" class="denomValue" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Could you post a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem; and what's `j(this)`, in context; where is your traversal *starting* from? Incidentally, if you want the value from the first element returned by that selector/traversal, you can omit the `eq()` since `val()` will automatically return the value from the first-matched field.

Comment: Are you claiming this works on other browsers?  I can't see how.

Comment: actually it does, works on FF and Chrome no issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with jQuery or IE 9 or jQuery version.

It is just that `.denomValue` is not a child of `.denom`.

> **.children( [selector ] )**
>
> Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Try using `.find` like below,

```
j(this).closest('.denom').find('.denomValue').eq(0).val();
```

**Assumption:** `this` is an element inside `.denom`

Answer (score 1):

You have an element between your `.denom` and `.denomValue` so `.children()` will not find it (it will only see the `<td>`s.

Try `.find()` instead

http://api.jquery.com/children/

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.